# Total number of cells in R numeric dataframe

Tags: code-golf, r

### Problem statement

The task is to write the shortest R statement to count the cells (rows * cols) in an instance of the R type `numeric data.frame`. For example, the `data.frame` which would be displayed as

```
  a    b  c
1 1 2000 NA
2 2 2000 NA
3 3 2000 1
4 4 2000 Inf
```

has 12 cells.

### Input

The `data.frame` is supplied in variable `x`. You may assume that it contains only numbers, boolean, `NA`, `Inf` (no strings and factors).

### Test cases

Example code to construct your own `data.frame`:

```
x <- merge(data.frame(a = 1:100), 
    merge(data.frame(b = 2000:2012), 
    data.frame(c = c(NA, 10, Inf, 30))))
```

The expected output is 15600.

### Appendix

Curious if someone can beat my solution :-) I don't want to take the fun from you so I will not reveal it now, I will only show you md5sum of my solution so that you later trust me in case you invent the same :-)

d4f70d015c52fdd942e46bd7ef2824b5

Comment: One example of input does not suffice to be a spec. What are the delimiters? Are the row and column headers guaranteed to be present? Can a cell be empty, and if so how is that represented? Also, you talk about people beating your solution, but you haven't specified a criterion for comparison.

Comment: @Peter, this is R challenge. You get `x` as a variable of type `data.frame`. It is not text input. I specified that in the question already. Ad the criterion - please read the question: *"construct as short command as possible*". Please if you don't understand, this is not reason for downvote.

Comment: @Peter, I've added an example of input data. Please retract the downvote.

Comment: Actually, "the question is unclear" is explicitly given as a reason for downvoting. I will try to clarify it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor this question seems pretty clear to me, perhaps because I am quite familiar with R.

Comment: @SimonO101, you're looking at the seventh revision.

Comment: @PeterTaylor point taken. It is all the better for the revisions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Naive:

```
> nrow(x)*ncol(x)
[1] 15600
```

First idea:

```
> prod(dim(x))
[1] 15600
```

Best I can do so far:

```
> length(!x)
[1] 15600
```

SimonO10 on the R chat had an idea (`sum(!(F&x))`), which I modded to get:

```
> sum(T|x)
[1] 15600
```

Note this doesn't work on factors, but you excepted those.

Comment: Very good! But it still can be few characters shorter ... :)

Comment: +1 joint honours I reckon unless Tomas has something sneaky up his sleeve!

Comment: `sum(x|T)` is my solution!!! You can check the md5 sum now!!! :-)

Comment: @Tomas How do you get that md5sum? I get `093130007d6f8d5d43e6bbab25f68733` for a file containing only `sum(x|T)`.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms you have to remove the newline - it is without newline.

Comment: @Tomas Thanks. I didn't think it had a newline, but `xxd -p` showed that it did.

Answer (score 12):

My best two attempts so far only got me down to 11 characters. I'd *love* to see fewer than @Spacedman's 10!

```
>sum( `[<-`(x,,,1) )
[1] 15600

>sum(!(F&x))
[1] 15600
```

## Got it!

```
sum(x^0)
[1] 15600
```

Comment: `NA^0` is 1? Whooda thunk it?

Comment: @Spacedman I know! It makes sense though right. NA is missing data, but *anything* `^` to 0 is `1`.

Comment: yes, but NA isn't anything :) It's absence of thing. Although I guess the argument is that even if you have a missing measurement for something you know that whatever it was to the zeroth power is going to be 1. NaN^0 == 1 is a bit more worrying (philosophically) though.

Comment: Agreed. I thought NA was a placeholder for missing data. Sicne this is numeric data it *has* to be a missing number therefore it *has* to resolve to 1. FWIW if you try x^0 on character column with `NA`s you correctly get an error.

Comment: @Spacedman what is even more worrying is that `is.numeric(NaN) == TRUE` :-) As well as in javascript, *"Not a Number"* IS number :D

Comment: you both guys now have the same length solution as me. Let's see if someone can make something even shorter :-)

Comment: @Tomas is yours the *same* as one of ours or do you have a third one that is the same length?

Comment: @SimonO101 see the comment on Spacedmans answer

Comment: `sum(1^x)` worked as well